# Folium mapping in wrong position

Tags: python, sql, maps, folium

I'm trying to create a program where data is pulled from an SQL db and then put out into the map.
It maps only **some points**, and when it does they are in Africa which is not where the **coordinates were set** in the db file.

```
import folium
import sqlite3

fga = folium.FeatureGroup(name="POI")
#Maps
map = folium.Map(location=[43.733777671205, -79.37156631524043], 
           zoom_start=11)

try:
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('cord.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    print("Connected to SQLite")

    sqlite_select_query = """SELECT longitude, latitude FROM cord;"""
        
    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        
    items = cursor.fetchall()
        
    for item in items:
        fga.add_child(folium.Marker(location = item[0]))
            
    cursor.close()

finally:
    if (sqliteConnection):
        sqliteConnection.close()
        print("The SQLite connection is closed")

map.add_child(fga)
map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())

map.save("CORD.html")
```

Comment: Flip your select statement from `longitude, latitude` to `latitude, longitude`